# Vertical check to flag only specified row in PySpark

Tags: pyspark, window, vertical-scrolling, process-mining

I need to do a check vertical on my dataset in PySpark to flag only row that match some condition.

In detail: I only have to flag only row where there is an "PURCHASE + SELLER" preceded by a "SALE + CUSTOMER" (bold in the example below).

Example:

`Input`

| id | order_type | Initiative | date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **1** | **PURCHASE** | **Seller** | **2022-02-11** |
| **1** | **PURCHASE** | **Seller** | **2022-02-10** |
| **1** | **PURCHASE** | **Seller** | **2022-02-09** |
| 1 | SALE | Customer | 2022-02-08 |
| 1 | SALE | Customer | 2022-02-07 |
| 1 | SALE | Customer | 2022-02-06 |
| **1** | **PURCHASE** | **Seller** | **2022-02-05** |
| 1 | SALE | Customer | 2022-02-04 |
| ***1*** | ***PURCHASE*** | ***Seller*** | ***2022-02-03*** (keep attention) |
| 2 | PURCHASE | Customer | 2022-02-11 |

`Output`

| id | order_type | Initiative | date | flag | difference (in days) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **1** | **PURCHASE** | **Seller** | **2022-02-11** | **1** | **3** |
| **1** | **PURCHASE** | **Seller** | **2022-02-10** | **1** | **2** |
| **1** | **PURCHASE** | **Seller** | **2022-02-09** | **1** | **1** |
| 1 | SALE | Customer | 2022-02-08 | 0 |  |
| 1 | SALE | Customer | 2022-02-07 | 0 |  |
| 1 | SALE | Customer | 2022-02-06 | 0 |  |
| **1** | **PURCHASE** | **Seller** | **2022-02-05** | **1** | **1** |
| 1 | SALE | Customer | 2022-02-04 | 0 |  |
| ***1*** | ***PURCHASE*** | ***Seller*** | ***2022-02-03*** | ***0*** (condition is not satisfied) |  |
| 2 | PURCHASE | Customer | 2022-02-11 | 0 |  |

---

Comment: Could you share your current code?

Comment: I haven't it... Sorry... I'm trying to do it now... But I'm not able...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here's my implementation

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from pyspark.sql.types import *
from pyspark.sql import Window

df = spark.createDataFrame(
    [
        ("1", "PURCHASE", "Seller", "2022-02-11"),
        ("1", "PURCHASE", "Seller", "2022-02-10"),
        ("1", "PURCHASE", "Seller", "2022-02-09"),
        ("1", "SALE", "Customer", "2022-02-08"),
        ("1", "SALE", "Customer", "2022-02-07"),
        ("1", "SALE", "Customer", "2022-02-06"),
        ("1", "PURCHASE", "Seller", "2022-02-05"),
        ("1", "SALE", "Customer", "2022-02-04"),
        ("1", "PURCHASE", "Seller", "2022-02-03"),
        ("2", "PURCHASE", "Customer", "2022-02-11"),
    ],
    ["id", "order_type", "Initiative", "date"],
)
df = df.withColumn("date", F.col("date").cast(DateType()))
df.show()

sale_df = df.filter((F.lower(F.col("order_type")) == "sale") & (F.lower(F.col("Initiative")) == "customer"))
sale_df.show()

row_window = Window.partitionBy(
    "df.id",
    "df.order_type",
    "df.Initiative",
    "df.date",
).orderBy(F.col("s.date").desc())

final_df = (
    df.alias("df")
    .join(
        sale_df.alias("s"),
        on=(
            (F.col("s.date") < F.col("df.date"))
            & (F.lower(F.col("df.order_type")) == "purchase")
            & (F.lower(F.col("df.Initiative")) == "seller")
        ),
        how="left",
    )
    .withColumn("row_num", F.row_number().over(row_window))
    .filter(F.col("row_num") == 1)    
    .withColumn("day_diff", F.datediff(F.col("df.date"),F.col("s.date")))       
    .withColumn(
        "flag",
        F.when(
            F.col("s.id").isNull(),
            F.lit(0),
        ).otherwise(F.lit(1)),
    )
    .select("df.*", "flag", "day_diff")
    .orderBy(F.col("df.id").asc(),F.col("df.date").desc())
)
final_df.show()
```

OUTPUTS:

```
+---+----------+----------+----------+
| id|order_type|Initiative|      date|
+---+----------+----------+----------+
|  1|  PURCHASE|    Seller|2022-02-11|
|  1|  PURCHASE|    Seller|2022-02-10|
|  1|  PURCHASE|    Seller|2022-02-09|
|  1|      SALE|  Customer|2022-02-08|
|  1|      SALE|  Customer|2022-02-07|
|  1|      SALE|  Customer|2022-02-06|
|  1|  PURCHASE|    Seller|2022-02-05|
|  1|      SALE|  Customer|2022-02-04|
|  1|  PURCHASE|    Seller|2022-02-03|
|  2|  PURCHASE|  Customer|2022-02-11|
+---+----------+----------+----------+

+---+----------+----------+----------+
| id|order_type|Initiative|      date|
+---+----------+----------+----------+
|  1|      SALE|  Customer|2022-02-08|
|  1|      SALE|  Customer|2022-02-07|
|  1|      SALE|  Customer|2022-02-06|
|  1|      SALE|  Customer|2022-02-04|
+---+----------+----------+----------+
```

final output:

```
+---+----------+----------+----------+----+--------+
| id|order_type|Initiative|      date|flag|day_diff|
+---+----------+----------+----------+----+--------+
|  1|  PURCHASE|    Seller|2022-02-11|   1|       3|
|  1|  PURCHASE|    Seller|2022-02-10|   1|       2|
|  1|  PURCHASE|    Seller|2022-02-09|   1|       1|
|  1|      SALE|  Customer|2022-02-08|   0|    null|
|  1|      SALE|  Customer|2022-02-07|   0|    null|
|  1|      SALE|  Customer|2022-02-06|   0|    null|
|  1|  PURCHASE|    Seller|2022-02-05|   1|       1|
|  1|      SALE|  Customer|2022-02-04|   0|    null|
|  1|  PURCHASE|    Seller|2022-02-03|   0|    null|
|  2|  PURCHASE|  Customer|2022-02-11|   0|    null|
+---+----------+----------+----------+----+--------+
```

Comment: thank u @iambdot, it works! I have added a further detail to my output. Could you consider the "difference" column (from the row with flag and the last previous "Sale Customer") in your code? Thanks!!!

Comment: @Jresearcher I updated the code to include the difference

Comment: @Jresearcher can you mark this as solved?

Comment: @Jresearcher can you mark this as solved?